# Not found: /accounts/facebook/login in django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to login the user using their social account and I am doing this with the help of Django allauth.

**What is the problem ?**

My project works fine on my laptop (which is broken now) but I don't know why it doesn't work on my desktop. I get the following error on the console whenever I try to login using a social account (Facebook in my case):

***Error:*** **`Not Found: /accounts/facebook/login`**

**My Code:**

***settings.py:***

```
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook'
]

LOGIN_URL = 'login_url'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout_url'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'redirect_url'

SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'Authentication.backends.EmailBackend',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {        
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.request'                
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

***html:***

```
<div class="modal" id="loginModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <form id='loginForm'>{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <a href="/accounts/facebook/login"> Facebook </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login"> Login </button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***urls.py:***

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

And have perfectly setup the social application for Facebook in my Django admin.

What could be wrong ? I had also copy pasted some of the files from my laptop's `Python27` directory to my desktop `Python27` directory but still getting the same error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found the solution and here its:**

You just have to reinstall django-allauth.

1. Uninstall django-allauth with the command `pip uninstall django-allauth`
2. And then install it again with the command `pip install django-allauth`