# using django-allauth + dj-rest-auth - Facebook don't appear in Admin panel

Tags: django, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I've started a fresh Django project and I'm using django-allauth + dj-rest-auth and according to this doc: https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional

I just need to add this on my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth'
    ...,
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    ...,
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
)

SITE_ID = 1
```

Now on my admin pannel I see "Social Network" and when I click on Provider, I can see only Twitter and Google but no Facebook at all. I tried to uninstall django-allauth and dj-rest-auth. Tried even to install them with previous versions and still the same.

Everyone who uses those packages on YouTube (or blogs) and wanna use Facebook does exactly like me and they got "Facebook" in the list.

[image]

Something is wrong but I don't know even why.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

[Not found: /accounts/facebook/login in django allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688793/not-found-accounts-facebook-login-in-django-allauth)

You just have to reinstall django-allauth.

Uninstall django-allauth with the command pip uninstall django-allauth

And then install it again with the command pip install django-allauth